# Spring Rest Controller in jar maven multi module

Tags: java, spring, rest, maven, spring-mvc

I have a maven multi module project. Currently the structure looks like:

1. Parent

   - ProfileManagement (Jar)
   - AccessManagement (Jar)
   - WebApp (War)

Currently WebApp has only jsps, html, css and javascript files. ProfileManagement and AccessManagement has Spring rest controllers, services, DAOs, etc.

My question is that should I pull the Spring Rest Controllers from the ProfileManagement and AccessManagement and put them in the WebApp or should I just keep them where they are now?

Right now I feel like even though ProfileManagement and AccessManagement are building jar files but they have the web component in them and it kind of feels wrong to me. What do you guys think??

Comment: Well if you are thinking to reuse the rest module for other webApplication is not bad to have in another module, I never done like that because I never have had to reuse a Rest module.

Comment: Thanks Paul, Do you think it would be better if we just  make the ProfileManagement and AccessManagement as standalone web applications instead of maven modules because that way it would b easier to reuse?

Comment: no, no, I would keep it as you have as jars. actually the good thing about How do you have is that is completely reuse-full in another maven project.

Answer (score 0):

Well if the individual modules ProfileManagement and AccessManagement are independent of each other and there there is no overlapping of URLMapping for the controllers in these modules then you should keep the respective controllers in the respective modules only.But in case of overlapping urlMappings you should pull them out to the parent module.

This will also allow the reusability of the modules in case you need it. I am sure you can use the Controllers for both rest and non rest calls, and use these controllers in parent module by just adding the modules as a dependency in the parent projects `pom.xml`.